# Run task periodically, *even when device is in idle*

Tags: android

I'm writing an app which should collect some sensor data every 10 seconds or so and write them to disk.

So far, I have an Activity which starts a service. The service has a runnable, which uses a handler to run my task periodically via `handler.postDelayed()`. See below for the (shortened) code.

So far, this works fine *as long as the device is active*. As soon as the device goes into idle, it doesn't run my task until it wakes up again.

**So, my question is how to run my task ALWAYS.**

With `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`, the AlarmManager seems to offer exactly what I need, but...

> To reduce abuse, there are restrictions on how frequently these alarms will go off for a particular application. Under normal system operation, it will not dispatch these alarms more than about every minute (at which point every such pending alarm is dispatched); when in low-power idle modes this duration may be significantly longer, such as 15 minutes.

Battery life has just a minor priority, though not being awake the entire time would be fine. (Not sure if android can be awake for just a second or so)

---

## MyActivity

```
...
public void onStartService(View view) {
    Intent i= new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyAppService.class);
    getBaseContext().startService(i);
}

public void onStopService(View view) {
    stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyAppService.class));
}
....
```

## MyService

```
public class MyAppService extends Service {

    MyRunnable mr;


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mr= new MyRunnable(getApplicationContext() );
        mr.Start();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mr.Stop();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

## MyRunnable

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

    // context is needed for sensorListener (?)
    private Context myContext;

    private Handler handler;

    public  MyRunnable(Context c){
        myContext=c;
        handler= new Handler();
    }

    public void Start(){
        run();
    }

    public void Stop(){
        handler.removeCallbacks(this);
        // some clean-up
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        //acquire and write to file some sensor data
        handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
    }

}
```

Comment: If this is about Marshmellow Doze, you could read this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/1361/alarmmanager/14777/api23-doze-mode-interferes-with-alarmmanager to create an exception for battery optimizations for your app. I am not sure whether or not this impacts the minimum interval for alarms though ...

Comment: @devnull69: Interesting, however, I also think this doesn't affect the maximum rate the AlarmManager allows.

Answer (score 0):

i think what you are looking for is STICKY SERVICE.

Officail Docs:   If the system kills the service after onStartCommand() returns, recreate the service and call onStartCommand(), but do not redeliver the last intent. Instead, the system calls onStartCommand() with a null intent, unless there were pending intents to start the service, in which case, those intents are delivered. This is suitable for media players (or similar services) that are not executing commands, but running indefinitely and waiting for a job.

you just need to pass a flag at the time of calling the service.

Comment: Thanks, but no. As the docs say: Services can be killed if android needs the ressources for other tasks. Sticky services are less likely to be killed and if they are, the system recreates them later. My service isn't killed, it just sleeps. (My service creates a new file on start and writes everything with timestamp to that file. I get a single file with gaps. If the service would be killed, I would get one file for each restart)